# Adding multiple event listeners dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

If I have a program that is adding and taking away html elements dynamically and each one of these elements needs to have an event listener is there a way to add the event listener to a variable that's easier than doing it one by one? I wanted to use an array and have each index of the array to have a event listener attached to it but that doesn't seem to work.

```
var1 = document.getElementById('name');
var1.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
```

This works fine but I have about 100 elements so I was hoping there is an easier way than creating 100 individual variables. I there is an easier way to do this I would love any suggestions. :)

Answer (score 5):

Code repetition can usually be avoided by using loops. In this case, create a list (array) of all IDs, and loop through it:

```
var names = ['name1', 'name2', 'etc'];
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(name[i]).addEventListener("mousedown",
                                                             doMouseDown, false);
}
```

If all of your elements have no descendants, you can also bind **one** event to the common parent, and check the `event.target` property:

```
var names = '|name1|name2|';
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    // Use String.indexOf, because old IE browsers do not support Array.indexOf
    if (names.indexOf( '|' + event.target.id + '|') !== -1) doMouseDown(event);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all these elements are children of a container element, you can add a single event listener to the parent element to capture all these events.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html for more info on the way javascript events are passed up and own the DOM tree.

Comment: Mozilla doesnt support this well - ive seen it in practice so although it is elegant solution it isnt the best solution  in terms of compatability.

Comment: @dudelgrincen - it does if you use an abstraction layer like Mootools or jQuery to take care of browser differences.

Answer (score 1):

you can organize your elements by giving them the same name and then putting them into array using **getElementsByName**. Afterwards you could loop through the array and add listeners to each element.